# CSS file is not loaded

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have a simple Django app and I cannot figure out why my CSS file is not loaded. Any help to nail the problem is appreciated!

The error that I am getting is this:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/aztracker/css/mystyle.css net::ERR_ABORTED`

This is where my css file is sitting: 
`myproject/aztracker/static/aztracker/css/mystyle.css`

**code_search_form.html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Search Code</title>
    <!-- CUSTOM STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'aztracker/css/mystyle.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="/search/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input  type="text" maxlength="2"  style="text-transform:uppercase"  placeholder="Search Country Code.." name="cc_textfield" id="cc_input">
        <button type="submit" id="search_btn">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**mystyle.css:**

```
#search_btn {
    color:red;
}
```

**setting.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    '/aztracker/static/',
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

the problems was the `setting.py` file where static folder is defined. I commented out `STATIC_ROOT` and it worked. I guess they cannot co-exist.

Comment: If you want to force loading css files and other static files the simply press CTRL + F5 since browser use cache to perform faster

Answer (score 0):

I am not the smartest when it comes to HTML but I know a few things. This may not change much but I can tell you how I do my linking.

```
<link href="css/CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" />
```

This is all I have done with my files so far, but I haven't ever tried to make a huge one. This works but everything, including the "% Static" I have never added to mine. Again I hope this helps but I don't know if it will change anything.

```
C:\Users\(User)\Desktop\Web\(ProjectName)\css\CSS
```

It Depends on where your HTML file is set in your project. Say I have this file structure.

```
C:\Users\(User)\Desktop\Web\Projects\HTMLProject\CSS\MainCSS\CSS.css
```

If your CSS file is in the MainCSS folder, but the HTML file is in your HTMLProject file, you would need to do  this instead.

```
<link href="CSS/MainCSS/CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" />
```

The more subfolders you have the more you need to explain to your computer how to get there.

Comment: This does not answer my question. You are stripping the django functionality, I need to keep it.