# Django container - serving static files

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I'm trying to put my API made with django-rest-framework into a docker container.

Everything seems to works except that I can't access to my static files.

Here is my *settings.py*:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

My *urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/bookmakers/', include('bookmakers.urls')),
    path('api/pronostics/', include('pronostics.urls')),
    path('api/', include('authentication.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My *Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

ADD requirements.txt /code/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& localedef -i fr_FR -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias fr_FR.UTF-8

ENV LANG fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE fr_FR
ENV LC_ALL fr_FR.UTF-8

RUN python --version

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /code/

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /code/

ENTRYPOINT ["/code/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

And finally my *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    db:
      image: postgres
      container_name: nyl2pronos-db
      restart: always
      environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        POSTGRES_DB: nyl2pronos


    website:
        container_name: nyl2pronos-website
        image: nyl2pronos-website
        build:
          context: nyl2pronos_webapp
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 3000:80

    api:
        container_name: nyl2pronos-api
        build:
            context: nyl2pronos_api
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: nyl2pronos-api
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            - DJANGO_PRODUCTION=1
```

So once I go to the url: http://localhost:8000/admin/, I can login but there is no css because the static files don't load.

```
GET http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/forms.css net::ERR_ABORTED 40
```

If you see another mistake, don't hesitate, just tell me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you using gunicorn to server django?

Comment: No, I'm only using python manage.py runserver

Comment: Are you using this configuration in local machine or in production?

Comment: I'm launching the 3 containers on my machine

Comment: Maybe you can look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46308543/2696165

Comment: I am providing an answer which is for production setup :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) or any production grade django server, they usually does not serve static contents. There are alternative ways to serve them. One of them is using [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/). You can try like this:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

And add a new middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

Another way is to use NGINX. I would suggest you can do it like this

```
# inside config/nginx/conf.conf  in source code

upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {

    location /static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /src/static/; 
    }

    location /media/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /src/media/; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    listen 8000;  
    server_name localhost;
}
```

Now update your docker compose to add NGINX and the configuration given above:

```
db:
  image: postgres
  container_name: nyl2pronos-db
  restart: always
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    POSTGRES_DB: nyl2pronos


website:
    container_name: nyl2pronos-website
    image: nyl2pronos-website
    build:
      context: nyl2pronos_webapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 3000:80

api:
    container_name: nyl2pronos-api
    build:
        context: nyl2pronos_api
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nyl2pronos-api
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
        - db
    environment:
        - DJANGO_PRODUCTION=1

nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nz01
    ports:
       - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
       - ./src:/src  # for syncing with django source code
       - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nyl2pronos-api
```

For more details, you can check my repository here: https://github.com/ruddra/docker-django or you can check [this post](https://ruddra.com/posts/serve-static-files-by-nginx-from-django-using-docker/) on how I configure NGINX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
So we agree on the fact I have to remove the service api from the docker-compose? And nginx will take care of the api side right? (Because I can't have two services listening on the same port)
Because right now what I have is: a webapp in Angular and an API in Django (Django-rest-framework)

Comment: And how I can also serve the media files static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) ?

Comment: @JérémyOcteau Basically the idea is to use a reverse proxy(like NGINX) to serve static contents. You can also serve media contents through NGINX. For that, you don't need to add media routes in `urls.py`. Just need to configure `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` in `settings.py`. I have updated the answer for serving media files through nginx.

Comment: But in the docker-compose I can't have to ports listening on 8000. So I changed in docker-compose the API server and added expose: -8000.
Then I changed all references from "web" to "api" in the Nginx config file.
So it works my static files are served. But for my uploaded files which are stored in my MEDIA_ROOT are not served because they are in my API container.

Comment: You can use `volume` to sync media content between two containers.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. should I modify my question an provide the configuration I used? Thank you a lot @ruddra !

Comment: Sure, you can do that. :)

Comment: Got me hitting my head to the wall for a while .. The location /static/... Must be placed before location /